# HTTP requests from Google Compute Engine to Appengine Standard

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

Is it possible to make secure HTTP requests from Google Compute Engine GCE to Google AppEngine GAE, without using service accounts and enabling the endpoints service (proxy) on the GAE service? Most of our backend HTTP handlers don't need the endpoints service proxy enabled, as the requests are all internal and not from the public. Our public API uses the compute engine endpoints service..

```
handlers:
- url: /securehandler/.*
  script: main.app
  login: admin
```

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/appref#handlers_element

"Note: the admin login restriction is also satisfied for internal requests for which App Engine sets appropriate X-Appengine special headers. For example, cron scheduled tasks satisfy the admin restriction, because App Engine sets an HTTP header X-AppEngine-Cron: true on the respective requests. However, the requests would not satisfy the required login restriction, because cron scheduled tasks are not run as any user."

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/appidentity/

"Asserting identity to other App Engine apps

If you want to determine the identity of the App Engine app that is making a request to your App Engine app, you can use the request header X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid. This header is added to the request by the URLFetch service and is not user modifiable, so it safely indicates the requesting application's ID, if present.

In your application handler, you can check the incoming ID by reading the X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid header and comparing it to a list of IDs allowed to make requests."

Obviously no X-AppEngine and X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid headers are set when making HTTP requests with the Go client in GCE.

Edit:

- url: /securehandler/.*
  script: _go_app
  login: required
  secure: always

Will default service accounts authenticate if login is set to required?

Answer (score 0):

If you do an HTTP request from GCE it will not include any credentials, so will not appear as logged-in. GAE does not provide a mechanism for API calls to pass login:required.

GAE does provide authentication as part of [Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/about-cloud-endpoints-frameworks). You can use this to authenticate requests from GCE.

Comment: We might have to enable IAP. We're using Go which doesn't support cloud endpoints in GAE standard. thanks tho.

Comment: Not sure if this will work without IAP tho google.DefaultClient(ctx, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform) https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2/google#example-ComputeTokenSource